# No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was trying to implement Pageable in my RestController and running into issues with this error message "No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable"

My Controller is

```
@GetMapping("/rest/category/all/page")
public Page<ItemCategory> getAllItemCategoryByPage(Pageable pageable){
    Page<ItemCategory> categories = itemCategoryService.getAllItemCategoriesByPageable(pageable);
    return categories;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here. It is a Spring Boot 2.0 Application. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest refactoring you controller to

```
public List<ItemCategory> getAllItemCategoryByPage(@RequestParam("page") int pageIndex, 
                                                   @RequestParam("size") int pageSize){
     return itemCategoryService
                   .getAllItemCategoriesByPageable(PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize)).getContent();
}
```

I think you are missing an annotation before Pageable (how are you sending that data from client?).

Comment: http://localhost:8080/rest/category/all/page?page=1&size=1
This is how I am calling the controller

Comment: Yes, Thank you! It Worked! Just one change instead of using new PageRequest(page, size) which is deprecated, I have used `Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);`

Comment: Thanks, I too have used this solution, just added default values to be safe.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem with the WebFlux app. Spring Boot 2.4.0 misses the corresponding `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` for the reactive apps but luckily provide working resolver implementation. You can enable it in the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class PageableWebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureArgumentResolvers(ArgumentResolverConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addCustomResolver(new ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```

Comment: This is still an issue in `spring-boot 2.6.8`.  Above solution worked 100% when using `spring-boot-starter-webflux`

Answer (score 18):

The selected solution is a workaround. You can make Spring resolve the parameters automatically using this configuration :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;
import org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add( new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

Comment: just an addition to above perfect solution, please also include @@EnableWebMvc in your configuration with spring boot 2.3.* onwards as your WebMvcConfigurer implementation is enabled by @EnableWebMvc. It will allow injection of Pageable instances into controller methods automatically created from request parameters.

Answer (score 12):

If you use [Clément Poissonnier's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52926137/5818405), **check if a configuration class do not override another one**.

I had the same problem and the solution below could not fix it:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add( new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

I still had the message:

> No primary or default constructor found for interface
>   org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable

I then realized **the project had a Swagger configuration class**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    // Swagger configuration...
}
```

and that the above **WebMvcConfig configuration was ignored**.

The solution was to have only one configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    // Swagger configuration...

    @Override
        public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
            argumentResolvers.add( new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
        }
    }
}
```

You might also no need **@EnableSpringDataWebSupport** as pointed by [John Paul Moore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55766329/5818405)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. You saved my day. ^^

Answer (score 12):

You can configure your test as:

```java
@BeforeEach
public void setup(){
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(messageController)
    .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver())
    .build();
}
```

See explanation https://www.javafixing.com/2021/12/fixed-request-is-not-being-executed-in.html

Comment: Working with Spring Boot 2.2.7 `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` is not needed when I'm using `SpringBootTest` and `AutoConfigureMockMvc`

Comment: Saved my day!!! While I was testing Pageable method

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the answers already given regarding enabling @EnableSpringDataWebSupport using the annotation. This should already be enabled with spring boot auto configuration. You may need to check your configuration, or is this auto configuration class being excluded using java config or in application properties.

```
   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Non Spring Boot Code:**

I was dealing with some existing spring mvc code base without spring boot, there was already a `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean registered in the xmls, so I had to do this

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        ...
        <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```